# How to execute an angular library independently without the shell UI

Tags: angular, angular-library

We have shell UI where all the angular custom libraries developed by our developers will be integrated.
The problem here is, whenever the developers wants to some development in the library they have to do in the integrated environment with shell UI and have to do the following steps which takes some time,

1. yarn build --watch in the library
2. yarn link in the shell UI app.
   The shell UI will set the user authentication and user context which helps the library to execute on that context.

Is there any way that the library can be run independently by stimulating the user context in the library level ? So that this will save some time for the developers not to do development in the integrated environment.

Comment: yes, I am also facing the same issue. Would love to find a way